# I have written the code for a PLSQL exception handler, but still it's not passing the test case in HackerRank

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, plsqldeveloper

> Write a PLSQL block to fetch distinct department ids which is assigned to employees in EMP table. Department details such as dept name and all needs to be retrieved from DEPT Table. SQL integrity constraints are not followed here, and so you may find records which are not available in DEPT Tables. Make sure to handle all the required exceptions to take care of these records.
>
> Schema details are:
>
> ```
> TABLE NAME         COLUMN NAMES
> ------------       -------------------------------------------------
> DEPT               DEPT_HEAD, DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME
>
> EMP                DEPT_ID, EMP_ACTIVEFROM, EMP_DOB, EMP_FNAME, EMP_ID, EMP_LNAME, 
>                            EMP_SAL, EMP_STATUS, EMP_TERMINATIONDATE, LOC_ID, MGR_ID
> ```

I have written the code, but every time I run this, the output is coming similar to what is asked in the question but it's not passing the Test case.

[Question screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Y7c.png)

[Test Case error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEtOG.png)

My code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    l_dept_name dept.dept_name%type;
BEGIN
    for cur_r in(select distinct e.dept_id from EMP e)
    loop
        begin
            select d.dept_name into l_dept_name from DEPT d where d.dept_id = cur_r.dept_id;
            dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID: '|| cur_r.dept_id||' is '||l_dept_name);
        exception
            when NO_DATA_FOUND then
                dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID: '|| cur_r.dept_id ||' is not a valid ID');
        end;
    end loop;
END;
/
EXIT;
```

Comment: You don't need this loop (containing another `SELECT`).  The cursor can be adjusted to return only those `dept_id` values which `EXISTS` in `emp.dept_id`.  There is no need for the `DISTINCT` use when using `WHERE EXISTS (...)`.

Comment: Your question doesn't include some detail required by the test.  You can use an `OUTER JOIN` to detect the missing cases.

Comment: Answer updated with both the wrong procedure and the corrected procedure.  I didn't replace your extra `SELECT` statements.  I just used them as is, with one small adjustment to refer to the new `isexists` derived column from the cursor.

Comment: Perhaps there is nothing wrong with procedure, it appears fine. The issue may be your results just do not have enough information. I.E. you failed to meet the requirements. The requirements clearly state *Department details such as dept name and all needs to be retrieved*. That would seem to say output must have DEPT_HEAD, DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME. Have you tried that?

Comment: The stated question is ambiguous.  It's not answerable without guessing.  That's not a very good way to phrase any hacker rank question.  Someone should take that question down or replace it.  `Department details such as dept name and all needs to be retrieved` ... does not match the requested output or the output generated isn't all that is required.  For instance:  *You didn't fetch all the columns of the DEPT table.*  Maybe that's your problem.  There are other issues with the wording.

Answer (score 0):

Test case with your SQL to show the result is missing rows:

[Fiddle with the procedure, and the corrected procedure](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0ee036c021da3bc0dbca021cc066c7e2)

```
CREATE TABLE dept (dept_id int, dept_name varchar2(10));

CREATE TABLE emp  (dept_id int);

BEGIN
INSERT INTO dept VALUES (1, 'd1');
INSERT INTO dept VALUES (3, 'd3');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (2);
END;
/

SELECT dept.dept_id, dept.dept_name, emp.dept_id AS isExists
  FROM dept FULL JOIN emp ON dept.dept_id = emp.dept_id
;

-- The original procedure, with missing results:
DECLARE
    l_dept_name dept.dept_name%type;
BEGIN
    for cur_r in(select distinct e.dept_id from EMP e)
    loop
        begin
            select d.dept_name into l_dept_name from DEPT d where d.dept_id = cur_r.dept_id;
            dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID: '|| cur_r.dept_id||' is '||l_dept_name);
        exception
            when NO_DATA_FOUND then
                dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID: '|| cur_r.dept_id ||' is not a valid ID');
        end;
    end loop;
END;
/
```

The results:

```
dbms_output:
Dept ID: 2 is not a valid ID
Dept ID: 1 is d1
```

Notice dept_id = 3 is missing in this result.

That's why you need something like a `FULL JOIN` to detect both missing types, both `dept_id` not contained in `emp` and `dept_id` in `emp` that doesn't exist in `dept`.

**Now the corrected procedure:**

I didn't remove the unnecessary `SELECT INTO` statements.  Those aren't really needed, since the cursor contains everything you need.

```
-- The new procedure, with all expected results:

DECLARE
    l_dept_name dept.dept_name%type;
BEGIN
    for cur_r in(
        SELECT DISTINCT dept.dept_id, dept.dept_name, emp.dept_id AS isExists
          FROM dept FULL JOIN emp ON dept.dept_id = emp.dept_id
        )
    loop
        begin
            select d.dept_name into l_dept_name from DEPT d where d.dept_id = cur_r.dept_id;
            dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID: '|| cur_r.dept_id||' is '||l_dept_name);
        exception
            when NO_DATA_FOUND then
                dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID: '|| cur_r.isexists ||' is not a valid ID');
        end;
    end loop;
END;
/
```

**The correct result:**

```
dbms_output:
Dept ID: 1 is d1
Dept ID: 2 is not a valid ID
Dept ID: 3 is d3
```

Notice `dept_id = 3` is in the result.

If we want the order guaranteed in `dept_id` order, we can add the following to the cursor query:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(dept.dept_id, isExists)
```

**Original answer with description:**

Your attempt doesn't detect the cases where a `dept.dept_id` exists which is not associated with an `emp` row.  Your SQL only finds dept_id's which are referenced by the `emp` table.

The cursor only needs to be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dept.*
     , emp.dept_id AS isExists
  FROM dept FULL JOIN emp ON dept.dept_id = emp.dept_id
;
```

This provides the distinct list of all dept detail, as requested, plus a column indicating if an employee record was found for the corresponding department.

When an `emp` row refers to an invalid `dept_id`, `dept.dept_id` will be null, and the `isExists` column in the result contains that missing `dept_id`.

`FULL JOIN` detects both `emp.dept_id` which is not in `dept` table and `dept.dept_id` which is not found in the `emp` table.

Test case:

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0ee036c021da3bc0dbca021cc066c7e2)

```
WITH emp  (dept_id) AS (SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION SELECT 2 FROM dual)
   , dept (dept_id) AS (SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION SELECT 3 FROM dual)
SELECT dept.dept_id, emp.dept_id AS isExists
  FROM dept FULL JOIN emp ON dept.dept_id = emp.dept_id
;
```

Result:

| DEPT_ID | ISEXISTS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| null | 2 |
| 3 | null |

Comment: I tried running the suggested SELECT but it's not clearing the test case in Hackerrank. The SELECT statement is asking for an INTO clause. :(

Comment: @AbhijitBiswas Correction.  Your SQL is only finding the invalid `dept_id` in `emp`, but not those dept_id's which are not found in the `emp` table.

Comment: @AbhijitBiswas Your logic does not find the 3rd case in my example, since there is no `emp` row which contains `dept_id = 3`.  You're only searching the `emp` table for the list of dept_id's.

Comment: @AbhijitBiswas Btw, I've only provided the cursor query, not any of the `SELECT ... INTO ...` logic.  The cursor should support any `SELECT ... INTO ...` you need, plus that extra column that indicates whether an `emp` row matched the given `dept_id`.

Comment: @AbhijitBiswas Nowhere in the test question you posted does it say anything about `SELECT INTO`.  There's no need to do that.  Just refer to the cursor directly and check for null as needed to detect which exception cases were found.  No exception handler is needed.  The nulls provide that detail.

Comment: I just need to pass the test case. Even if I add extra stuff check other queries it's still treated as error. Hackerrank doesn't consider anything else other than the Test Case. I'm getting the output, it's not clearing the Test Case. I'm trying to keep my code simple and I'm just following the instructions in the questions. You couldn't help me. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @AbhijitBiswas Sure. That's part of the problem. You don't know the actual test case.  There is a clear reason your logic would not meet all the criteria. I explained the reason and provided a query you can use in your cursor.  Review my test case and then try your logic against it.  You'll see that your result does not match mine.  Your logic will not produce a result containing all the rows expected.  The rows you do produce are ok.  But you're missing results.

Answer (score 0):

The question is:

> Write a PL/SQL block to fetch the distinct department ids which is assigned to employees in the EMP table.

You only need to fetch the `DEPT_ID` values from the `EMP` table and check if they are valid (i.e. they exist in the `DEPT` table); you do not need to print any ids in the `DEPT` table that do not exist in the `EMP` table so using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` is wrong.

---

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the cursor:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                   e.dept_id,
                   d.dept_name
            FROM   EMP e
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPT d
                   ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id)
  LOOP
    IF r.dept_name IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Dept_ID :'||r.dept_id|| ' is not a valid ID');
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Dept_ID :'||r.dept_id|| ' is '||r.dept_name);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*Also, take care that you format the output so that it matches the expected output.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dept (dept_id, dept_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Dept_name1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Dept_name2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Dept_name4' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE emp (emp_id, dept_id) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Dept_ID :1 is Dept_name1
> Dept_ID :4 is Dept_name4
> Dept_ID :3 is not a valid ID
> Dept_ID :5 is not a valid ID
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8b6dfe0222b793e69b9e93e491762319)*